# Where I can download the Wubi installer for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: wubi

I just download the Wubi installer for Ubuntu 11.10 and gives me an error. And in a forum someone says me that if I can try downloading the Wubi installer for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS but, I'm seeking it about 30 mins and I can't find it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

you can get the 10.04 wubi installer [from here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/).

You're looking for the file `wubi.exe` which is right at the bottom, or you can click [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/wubi.exe) link and download it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for 10.04 wubi [installer](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/) information or manual installation with information, instructions, specs, and requirements.

And you can download it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/wubi.exe). That link if for the ***wubi.exe*** executable file.