# Download wubi 10.04

Tags: 10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where I can download the Wubi installer for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113969/where-i-can-download-the-wubi-installer-for-ubuntu-10-04-lts)

I would like to download an older version of ubuntu ( 10.04 for instance ). Does anyone know where can I find the windows installer? ( Note: I don't want to burn to disk )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it from [Ubuntu Releases Ubuntu 10.04.4LTS (Lucid Lynx)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/).  Look toward the bottom of the list.  Remember that doing it this way will need Internet access.  I recommend that you do download 10.04, and burn it to a CD.

To download other releases, you can choose the one you want from the [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) download page.